# Omitted Variables and their consequences for other variables

Tags: least-squares, endogeneity

Suppose we have the following regression model:
$$
y_{i}=\boldsymbol{x_{i}'\beta}+e_{i}
$$
where the vector $\boldsymbol{x_{i}'}$ contains two variables, $[x_{1i}\,x_{2i}].$Suppose
for a second, that $e_{i}$ contains variables that correlated with
$x_{1i}$. The well known omitted variables bias tells us that $\beta_{1}$
will be measured with bias when estimated by OLS. However, what implications
does this have for $\beta_{2}?$ In other words, does bias in one
set of estimates still have implications for bias in a second set
of estimates? In other words, if $cov\left(x_{1i},e_{i}\right)\neq0$
, but $cov\left(x_{2i},e_{i}\right)=0,$ what does this mean for the
estimates of $\beta_{2}?$

Comment: Any updates? Seems like a straightforward question...

Comment: I think OLS will work fine for the coefficient $\beta_2$. No bias there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intuitively, the answer is that $\hat{\beta}_2$ will be biased whenever $x_2$ is correlated with $x_1$.  This is because the correlation of $x_2$ with $x_1$ causes $\hat{\beta}_2$ to be correlated with $\hat{\beta}_1$; as a consequence, when $\hat{\beta}_1$ differs from $\beta_1$, $\hat{\beta}_2$ will differ from $\beta_2$ in expectation, and, writing loosely, since we expect $\hat{\beta}_1$ to be biased, $\hat{\beta}_2$ will be too.

I'll assume away the intercept term for simplicity of exposition, without loss of generality.  Writing out the expression for $\mathbb{E}\hat{\beta}$ gives us:

$$\mathbb{E}\hat{\beta} = \mathbb{E}(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY = \mathbb{E}(X^TX)^{-1}X^T(X\beta + e) = \beta + \mathbb{E}(X^TX)^{-1}X^Te$$

Under the assumptions of the question, $\mathbb{E}X^Te$ can be written as $(\theta,0)$, where $\theta$ is a function of the nonzero covariance between $x_1$ and $e$.  Substituting gives us:

$$  \mathbb{E}\hat{\beta} - \beta = [(X^TX)^{-1}_{1,1}\theta, (X^TX)^{-1}_{2,1}\theta]$$

The subscripts designate which element of the $2 \times 2$ matrix $(X^TX)^{-1}$ is being referred to.

Since $(X^TX)^{-1}_{1,1} > 0$ unless $x_1$ is identically equal to $0$, we can see that $\hat{\beta}_1$ will be biased; however, $\hat{\beta}_2$ will be biased if and only if $(X^TX)^{-1}_{2,1} \ne 0$, i.e., if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are correlated.

Here's a simple example in R, where the true values of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are both equal to $1$:

```
bhat_1 <- rep(0, 10000)

V <- matrix(c(1,0.6,0.6,1), 2, 2)

for (i in 1:length(bhat_1)) {
  x <- rmvn(100, c(0,0), V)
  y <- x[,1] + x[,2] + rnorm(100)
  bhat_1[i] <- coef(lm(y~x[,1]))[2]
}


hist(bhat_1)
```

that produces the following histogram:
[image]

Comment: I see. Thanks for that. It is strange that even though x2 satisfies the requirement of being uncorrelated with the error, it is still biased because it is correlated with x1, which in turn is correlated with the error term. Is this intuition correct?  Also, if indeed this is the case, we can actually sign the bias, and correct for this bias by accounting for the sample correlation of x1 with x2.

Comment: Your intuition is correct, and i'll edit my answer to put a more intuitive gloss on what's going on.

Comment: @ChinG What seems to be landing with my intuition is that I can reorder the variables $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ in a *multiple* regression (i.e. so that I am *not* omitting variables) so that the data vectors swap names, and still expect to see identical $\beta$s and SEs. If that is the case, then if there is omitted variables bias for $\beta_{1}$ due to omission of $x_{2}$, I would guess that the the same must be true for $\beta_{2}$ if I omit $x_{1}$. Correlations are non-directional, after all. Of course, my intuition might have the utility of a stopped clock here... :)  (Also: +1 jbowman)

Comment: @Alexis - your intuition is correct; it really comes down to the structure of $X^TX$, and reordering the variables just rearranges the rows and columns, it doesn't change the covariances themselves.

Comment: This exposition is quite damning. In all the economics seminars I frequent, people only care about whether or not the variable of interest is exogenous to unobserved factors (i.e. if the variable can be interpreted in a causal sense). According to the line of reasoning displayed by @jbowman , one has to make sure that *all* the included variables are conditionally exogenous, otherwise mild correlation between regressors can render the coefficients on each one as biased.

Comment: Sad but true, and not only biased but also inconsistent.

Comment: In these cases, @jbowman, is it therefore not prudent to work with orthogonalized regressors? This would ensure that the correlation between them is 0 (so regress x1 on x2 and work only with the residuals).

Comment: At the cost of interpretability, and if one of your regressors is missing, you can't orthogonalize with respect to that one.  But isn't that getting closer to 2SLS, constructing instruments to get rid of endogeneity problems?

Comment: @ChinG To fair: while *correlation* is non-directional, *causality* is hella directional. Hernán & Robbins' [*Causal Inference: What If*](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/miguel-hernan/causal-inference-book/) does a good job of illuminating why in a *causal* model of $Y$ conditioned on $A$ (the intervention, possibly more than one variable), and $L$ (the conditioning covariates), the validity of the causal inference is for the effect of $A$ on $Y$, **and not** for the effect(s) of $L$ on $Y$.

Comment: @Alexis - first time I've seen "hella" used in this context, and it really makes the point!  I updated the example to remove any apparent causal relationship between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: @jbowman :D :D That's my Oaklandish Bay-Areanism sneaking in. :)

Comment: @ChinG On the other hand, if both $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ are *causes* of $y$, then "
This exposition is quite damning" becomes quite relevant, I think.

Comment: Just revisiting this question! @jbowman. One part that still irks me is that intuition suggests that x1 would need to be correlated with the part of x2 which is correlated with the error term. Imagine that x1 is correlated with the uncorrelated part of x2- in that case, x1 should still be able to identify the true parameter of interest, no?

Comment: Unfortunately, $x_1$ can't tell which part of $x_2$ it is correlated / uncorrelated with!  It only sees the whole thing, so you get a mix for the solution.  If you could split $x_2$ apart into $x_2 = x_2^a + x_2^b$ with $x_2^a$ uncorrelated with the error term and $x_2^b$ correlated with the error term, then the estimate of the coefficient of $x_2^a$ would indeed be unbiased, as you suspect.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what happens for any number of predictors and omitted variables. The answer ends up similar to what @jbowman (+1) showed for two predictors (one correlated with omitted variables and one not). Since I'd already started writing this, I'll post it in case it's useful to see another approach.

To summarize the answer below: Suppose $X_u$ contains predictors that are uncorrelated with all omitted variables and $X_c$ contains predictors that are correlated with at least one omitted variable. Then, under standard assumptions, OLS coefficients for predictors in $X_u$ are unbiased if and only if $X_u$ and $X_c$ are uncorrelated.

#### Setup

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector of responses and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ be a matrix of predictors. We also have predictors $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times q}$ that will be omitted. Assume the predictors and responses have been centered, so there's no need for an intercept term. I'll also assume that predictors may be correlated but not perfectly collinear (this implies that $X$ and $Z$ have full rank, and $n \ge p+q$).

Suppose true model is:

$$y = X w + Z v + \epsilon \quad \quad
\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(\vec{0}, \sigma^2 I)$$

where $w \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^q$ are the true coefficients, and $\epsilon$ is a random vector representing i.i.d. Gaussian noise with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$.

Say we fit an ordinary least squares regression model, omitting $Z$. The estimated coefficients are:

$$\hat{w} = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T y$$

The bias is a vector containing the expected difference between the estimated and true coefficients (see derivation below):

$$\text{bias}
= E[\hat{w} - w]
= (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Z v$$

Multiplying both sides by $X^T X$ gives:

$$X^T X \ \text{bias} = X^T Z v$$

#### For predictors uncorrelated with the omitted variables

Suppose the predictors are partitioned as $X = [X_u, X_c]$, where $X_u$ contains columns uncorrelated with all omitted variables and $X_c$ contains columns correlated with at least one omitted variable. So, $X_u^T Z = \mathbf{0}$ and $X_c^T Z \ne \mathbf{0}$. Similarly, suppose the bias is partitioned into subvectors $\text{bias}_u$ (for predictors in $X_u$) and $\text{bias}_c$ (for predictors in $X_c$). Rewrite the preceding equation in the partitioned form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
  X_u^T X_u & X_u^T X_c \\
  X_c^T X_u & X_c^T X_c
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \text{bias}_u \\ \text{bias}_c \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{0} \\ X_c^T Z \end{bmatrix} v$$

Break this into two systems:

$$X_u^T X_u \text{bias}_u + X_u^T X_c \text{bias}_c = \vec{0}$$

$$X_c^T X_u \text{bias}_u + X_c^T X_c \text{bias}_c = X_c^T Z v$$

$\text{bias}_c$ is nonzero, since assuming it's zero leads to a contradiction, given our assumptions. This recapitulates the standard statement about omitted variable bias.

More interestingly, the question concerns $\text{bias}_u$, the bias of predictors that are uncorrelated with the omitted variables. The first equation in the above pair leads to two conclusions: 1) If $X_u$ and $X_c$ are uncorrelated so $X_u^T X_c = \mathbf{0}$, then the only solution is $\text{bias}_u = \vec{0}$. Recall that $X$ has full rank so $X_u$ does too, and the null space of $X_u^T X_u$ includes only the zero vector. 2) Since $\text{bias}_c$ is nonzero, $\text{bias}_u = \vec{0}$ would imply that $X_u^T X_c = \mathbf{0}$.

Therefore, coefficients for predictors in $X_u$ have zero bias if and only if $X_u$ and $X_c$ are uncorrelated:

$$\text{bias}_u = \vec{0} \ \iff \ X_u^T X_c = \mathbf{0}$$

#### Derivation of the bias

The bias is the expected difference between the estimated and true coefficients, where the expectation is taken w.r.t. $\epsilon$:

$$\begin{array}{ccl}
  \text{bias} & = & E[\hat{w} - w] \\
  & = & E\big[ (X^T X)^{-1} X^T y - w \big] \\
  & = & E\big[
    (X^T X)^{-1} X^T X w
    + (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Z v
    + (X^T X)^{-1} X^T \epsilon
    - w
  \big] \\
  & = & E\big[ (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Z v + (X^T X)^{-1} X^T \epsilon \big] \\
  & = & (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Z v
  + E\big[ (X^T X)^{-1} X^T \epsilon \big] \\
  & = & (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Z v \\
\end{array}$$

Line 2 substitutes in the expression for $\hat{w}$. Line 3 substitutes the true model in for $y$. Line 4 is an algebraic simplification. Line 5 uses linearity of expectation. Since noise has zero mean and is uncorrelated with the predictors, the expectation in the last term is zero, giving line 6.